# Calculate the probability of each individual event; that is, calculate (), (), and ().

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A red and a blue die are thrown. Both dice are fair (that is, all sides are equally likely).
The events , , and  are defined as follows:
: The sum of the numbers on the two dice is at most 3.
: The sum of the numbers on the two dice is odd.
: The number on the red die is 3.
a. Calculate the probability of each individual event; that is, calculate (),
(), and ().

b. What is (|)?

c. What is (|)?

d. What is (|)?

e. Consider all pairs of events:  and ,  and , and  and . Which pairs of
events are independent?

**My attempt**

a) 
$p(A)=\frac { 3 }{ 36 } $=$\frac { 1 }{ 13 } $

$p(B)=\frac { 18 }{ 36 } $=$\frac { 1 }{ 1 } $

$p(C)=\frac { 1 }{ 6 } $

b) (|) = $\frac{P(A\cap B)}{p(B)}$ = $\frac{\frac { 1 }{ 18 }}{\frac { 1 }{ 2 }}$ = $\frac { 1 }{ 9 } $

c) (|) = $\frac{P(B\cap C)}{p(C)}$ = $\frac{\frac { 1 }{ 12 }}{\frac { 1 }{ 6 }}$ = $\frac { 1 }{ 2 } $

d) (|) = $\frac{P(A\cap C)}{p(C)}$ = 0. because there is no common for A and C.

can anyone verify this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts a,b,c,d all look good so far. For part e) just check either

$Pr(A|B)=Pr(A)$ or $Pr(A \cap B)=Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B)$

Hope this helps